# Javascript SetInterval Not Working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using window.open to open a popup window and setinterval function to wait and refresh the background page, once the popup is closed.
the code is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but is not working in IE.

Basically the issue is: in IE, it doesn't wait until popup window is closed. It immediately gets refreshed as soon as the popup opens up.
I saw the issue coming in both IE 9 & IE 11.

Any solution for this?

This is the code:

```
var url = "/apex/VFP_Add";
var win = window.open(url, "Add" ,"width=600, height=300, scrollbars=yes"); 
win.moveTo(500, 100); 
win.focus(); 
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
if(win.closed) { 
clearInterval(timer); 
window.location.reload(); 
} 
}, 500);
```

I put alerts just before if(win.closed) check and just after the check. For the first alert, it showed as False. In second alert, after "if check", it showed True. This is very weird because i had not closed the window.

Comment: Please specify the IE versions that you've seen the problem with.

Comment: rather than periodically checking if child window is closed, just do something in `onbeforeunload` event handler of child window

Answer (score 1):

It seems that's a known bug in IE. See this article about it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/241109

Their solution is to basically negate the value of `win.closed` when you detect that it's running in IE. Something like:

```
if(win.closed || isRunningInIE()) {
    clearInterval(timer); 
    window.location.reload(); 
}
```

There are different ways to detect IE, so you can just use your favorite method in place of that `isRunningInIE()` function.

Comment: Thanks zaparaker. even if i use negation it didn't work, finally i went with jquery based solution.